# How to get the number of elements found using Selenium WebDriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I looked at the documentation located [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/), but couldn't find an answer.

I want to get an element by `class name` or `xpath` and return the number of instances. There seems to be no available function in Python, such as `get_xpath_count()`.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` and count the number of returned elements.

Comment: doh! good catch! I was looking at the singular find_element_by_xpath() which was listed in the Locating Elements section and it only returned a single WebElement object. The plural function you stated was actually located in section 6 "API". Not sure why they didn't include this in section 4 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it would make sense at least making a brief mention in section 4, strange but at least there are some docs!

Comment: I'm gonna edit the doc on github and hopefully it gets pulled.

Answer (score 10):

You Can simply use `len()` function:

```
len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a'))
```

Answer (score 3):

In java, the following could work:

```
int xpathCount= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='billingProfiles']/div[@class='cardContainer']")).size();
```

OR,

```
List<WebElement> xpath = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='billingProfiles']/div[@class='cardContainer']"));
int xpathCount = xpath.size();
System.out.println("Total xpath: " + xpathCount);
```

For counting the total links in a page:
**Way1:**

```
List<WebElement> totalLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
int totalLinkSize = totalLinks.size();
System.out.println("Total Links by Way1 : " + totalLinkSize);
```

**Way 2:**

```
int totalLinkSize2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a")).size();
System.out.println("Total Links by Way2 : " + totalLinkSize2);
```

Comment: is this the best way in java?

Comment: The above is one of the ways. You can do it by different way also. You can use List<WebElement>

Comment: okay, that is what i am doing right now, but is there another way like a method that will return an int object?

Comment: You can write a method yourself by using the above code.

Comment: this isn't a valid answer.  the OP tagged the question as Python, not Java

Answer (score 1):

In python

```
element.find_elements()
```

will return all surface children Web Elements

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
count_elemnts = len(driver.find_elements_by_...('name or class or id or xpath'))
```

**elements (with an s) and not element**

Comment: Just adding a brief explanation, for others. Elements (with an s) is used here over just the non-pluralised Element because it iterates over the whole list, instead of just one element. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520898/20331138 

The len() function is also implemented as it helps to calculate the length of the list object, or the number of instances of elements in the list i.e. the count of data items present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IWebDriver driver = null;

public static IList<IWebElement> elements;

// List count return total number of element

elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a"));

int intLinkCount = elements.Count;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'assertXpathCount' command available in Selenium