# TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract all the links from wikipedia homepage but this code showing  TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable error.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
search=[]
search=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href]')


for ii in search:
  print(ii.get_attribute('href'))

time.sleep(4)
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `find_element_by_xpath` which return only one WebElement (which is not iterable), the `find_elements_by_xpath` return a list of WebElements.

Solution: replace `find_element_by_xpath` with `find_elements_by_xpath`

[Reference: selenium-python docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: The same is true for find_element vs find_elements. Thanks!

Comment: This method is deprecated and should be replaced by `find_element('xpath', ...)` and `find_elements('xpath', ...)` respectively. The link is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Below code worked for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
list_links=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for i in list_links:
    print i.get_attribute('href')
```