# issue with selenium - find_elements_by_xpath or find_elements_by_tag

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, selenium

I'm having an issue where I'm not sure where lies the issue.

I've created a functional test for, called `func_tests1.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import unittest


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()


    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()


    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')   

        #this is where lies the issue
        header_text = self.browser.find_element_by_tag('h1') 
        self.assertIn('To-do', header_text)

        self.fail('Finish the test!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

This is my template, `home.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>To-do lists</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Your To-do list <h1>
    <input id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item"/>
    <table id="id_list_table">
    </table>
  </body>
<!--   -->
</html>
```

When I do a `python3 func_tests1.py`, I have the following error :

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "func_tests.py", line 44, in test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it
    self.assertIn('To-do',header_text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 1086, in assertIn
    if member not in container:
TypeError: argument of type 'FirefoxWebElement' is not iterable
```

After, doing some search on the internet, I found this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520426/typeerror-webelement-object-is-not-iterable-error),which is changing the line
`header_text = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag('h1')` 
to
`header_text = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('h1')`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import unittest


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()


    def tearDown(self):
            self.browser.quit()


    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')   

        header_text = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('h1') #changing to the new method
        self.assertIn('To-do', header_text)


        self.fail('Finish the test!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore'
```

And suddenly, this new error is appearing.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "func_tests.py", line 44, in test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it
    self.assertIn('To-do',header_text)
AssertionError: 'To-do' not found in []

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 3.369s
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: Your `self.browser.title` is an empty list and when you try to find "To-do"(using [assertIn(x,y)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn)) in it, it gives the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is how `header_text` is defined.

`header_text = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag('h1')` will return a **list** of `FirefoxWebElement`.

If you only need the first element, you can use

```
header_text = self.browser.find_element_by_tag('h1')  # no plural
```

This one returns only the first matching `FirefoxWebElement`.

---

Now, to anticipate the next error, if you want to compare any text, you also need to select the `text` attribute of this `FirefoxWebElement`.

```
header_text = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text

self.assertIn('To-do', header_text) # >>> OK
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider adding an id to the header:

```
<h1>Your To-do list <h1>
```

becomes

```
<h1 id="todolist">Your To-do list <h1>
```

Then, you can simply

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("todolist")
```

Might be cleaner than a xpath/tag solution: as the page grows, an id should be unique, whereas other header tags might be added.

Comment: hi @serv-inc, that is very very smart actually, using the id to test the html.