# print python using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
import time 
import os 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")             
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select") 
li=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]') 
for i in li: 
    print(i.text) 
driver.close()

for i in li:
    TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath` --> `find_elements_by_xpath`. The first returns only the first matching object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520426/typeerror-webelement-object-is-not-iterable-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`li=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]')` will return a single element and you can't iterate using webelement.

You should use `li=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]//li')`, if you want to get a list of elements matching with that xpath.