# Python Selenium - Attempting to write wait condition for when text changes in table element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, browser-automation

I am attempting to write a selenium script to search for terms on a webpage, then select them from a table.

The table is dynamic and changes when elements are entered into the search field. Typically when I have written selenium code in the past, I have just used wait statements to wait for some element on the page to load before continuing. With this, I specifically need to wait until the element I am looking for to appear in the table, and then to select it.

Here is what I currently have written, where tableElement is the table I attempting to search through, and userID is the input I am hoping to find:

```
tableElement = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                'X-PATH_TO_ELEMENT')

ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
                EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
                    tableElement, userID)
            )
```

When running this code, I receive the following error message:

```
find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
```

As far as I am aware, this should be the correct syntax for the method I am attempting to call. Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if I need to elaborate on any details.

Comment: I think you are hitting the error that the element you are looking for is not single element on the screen, please check if this help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520898/415749

Answer (score 1):

`Expcted condition` are basically used with `find_element` and `find_elements`.

In your code you have provided web element to EC instead of locator.

you can use below code to use EC in your code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
             EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "xpath of your element")))
```

Note: you have to add below importss to your solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: I have changed my code to reflect this change, and am now using the tuple of By.XPATH and "xpath to element" as an arguement to the function:

`
ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
                EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                    (By.XPATH,
                     '//*[@id="table_content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table")'), userID)
            )
`

However, now I am getting the following error message:
`__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: What is userID it is not valid as per EC conditon :: ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until( EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located( (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table_content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table')))

Comment: @SonOfGritty : If you want to check your content  present in td you can use something like this ://*[@id="table_content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/table//td[text()="My Content"]